# SpotBugs ignore whole directory in src folder

Tags: maven, findbugs, spotbugs

Hy,

In my maven setup, I have a plugin, which generates source code and puts it into my java `src` folder.
As this code is auto generated, I'd like to exclude it from all SpotBugs checks.

The file structure is as follows:

```
-- src
    |
    --- generated    <-- No files in this folder should be checked
    |
    --- main         <-- The "normal" java files, which should be checked
```

I tried a few things including the following, but nothing works:

```xml
<FindBugsFilter>
  <Match>
    <Source name="~.*generated.*"/>
  </Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

This is my plugin configuration in the pom.xml:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <excludeFilterFile>config/spotbugs-excludes.xml</excludeFilterFile>
    <effort>Max</effort>
    <threshold>Normal</threshold>
    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
    <includeTests>false</includeTests>
    <spotbugsXmlOutput>true</spotbugsXmlOutput>
    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.h3xstream.findsecbugs</groupId>
        <artifactId>findsecbugs-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mebigfatguy.fb-contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>fb-contrib</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.3.sb</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Greets
Chris

Comment: `src/generated` does not follow convention. Usually generated directory is created in `target` directory instead. I would suggest to cleanup your configuration and follow conventions...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'd love to, but the plugin in question is not maintained by me and I have no choice but to use it as is

Comment: could you solve this? I'm going through the same issue

Comment: I wasn't. What I did is looking at the auto generated files and finding that they all had similar name suffixes. Thus I just added that suffix to the ignores check and made sure to not use the same suffix in my actual sources